# psql no response after trying to login

Tags: psql

When trying to login to psql the terminal does not give any response (not even a mistake).
(when I type a wrong password or a non-existent user if I get an error in reply)
[remains so without giving any further answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8420.png)

I tried just waiting a long time to see if I could login, but I could not.